# How to change color of the selection and not the entire block with Gutenberg palette?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using WordPress for a website and I already changed the default colors palette of Gutenberg with something like this :

```
function mytheme_setup_theme_supported_features() {
    add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'pda-main', 'pda' ),
            'slug' => 'pda-main',
            'color' => '#E7344C',
        )
    ) );
}
```

The problem is that when I select a color in the administration; Gutenberg changes the entire block and not the selection only

Is there a possibility to change the color of the selection and not the entire block ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible with the default Gutenberg plugin..

BUT

I found an answer at the same problem and found a plugin that overrides Gutenberg behavior which was developed by iseulde (a frequent Gutenberg and WordPress Core Contributor and Member of WordPress Organisation and Automattic)

You can download the plugin here : [Advanced rich text tools](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-rich-text-tools/)

Source : [WordPress Support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-color-to-individual-text-within-text-blocks-in-gutenburg/)

I hope it will help other people